# Latest Chrome breaks Stack Snippets (113.0.5672.126)

Tags: bug, stack-snippets, google-chrome

I've just upgraded my Google Chrome to version 113.0.5672.126 (Official Build) (arm64) on macOS 13.2.1.

But afterwards, all Stack Snippets stopped working

- I've uninstalled all my extensions
- I've cleared my Cookies + Local storage
- Restarted laptop

---

- There are no errors in the browser console
- Network tab shows a 200 on the https://stacksnippets.net/js request, with an empty response

---

- The Snippets do seem to work in an incognito tab.

---

Please suggest how I could debug/fix this.

Screen recording of a random non-working snippet:
[image]

<sup>Click the GIF for original size</sup>

Comment: No repro in FF 113.0.1 (64 bit) nor in Chrome 113.0.5672.126 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Glad it seems to be caused by my device, if somebody could suggest some tips to resolve/debug this that would be great.

Comment: In a recent episode, [Gibson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Now) talked about some upcoming changes to Chrome this month. Sorry, I can't provide a more accurate reference at this point in time (but high-quality transcripts are available).

Comment: "_The Snippets do seem to work in an incognito tab._" could you clear your cookies and try? Are you also sure that you don't have any extensions remaining (Incognito mode can have different settings for extensions)?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat thanks for your suggestion. Clearing cookies + local storage does not have any effect. All extensions are uninstalled, for both normal and incognito.

Comment: @PeterMortensen I'm not sure what you're suggesting.

Comment: Do *any* snippets not work or just this concrete example?

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine Unfortunately **all** Stack Snippets stopped working.

Comment: @0stone0 huh, weird. Out of curiosity, how does the payload for the `https://stacksnippets.net/js` endpoint look like for you?

Comment: When pressing the 'run' button, there is 1 request to stacksnippets, that results in a 200, but without any response. The Chrome network preview and response tabs shows literally nothing.

Comment: @0stone0 thanks - although I meant the payload the client sends to the endpoint (one other thing of interest - what's the content-type header of the response?). It's weird enough that the response is empty as it should contain a document to insert into an iframe.

Comment: Ahh sorry, the request content-type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. The payload is the encoded code on the `js` key with an additional `css`, `html`, `console` and `babel` keys. That seems just fine. Response still empty tho.

Comment: @0stone0 yup, seems fine. Dunno, out of ideas, to be honest. Have you tried fully logging out and logging back in SO (just in case)? Shooting in the dark here. Odd that they work in the incognito mode.

Comment: Don't worry, glad you're thinking along. While clearing cookies + local storage I had to login again, didn't work :( Yea can't find any reason why I'd work only in incognito tho... I must be missing something

Comment: @0stone0 yeah, that would've cleared the `acc` cookie. Huh, I really don't know then: payload's fine, response is *generally* fine, no extensions. It's probably time to contact the company... Another check - what the *response* content-type header?

Comment: Have you restarted your computer? Also, have you checked an HTML/CSS snippet or just JS to see which parts of Stack Snippets are broken for you?

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine Are you testing on macOS or another OS?

Comment: @TylerH tested on Linux Mint 21.1

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine hmm... so we can't technically exclude the problem to be macOS-specific.